# Iterate multiple JSON Objects in POST request via Python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, post

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io
from lib2to3.pgen2.token import LESS
from locale import format_string
from turtle import back
import requests
import json
import sys
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

### ONLY PROVEN FOR ONE OBJECT AT A TIME


#data = open('commandoutputid.json') 
#data = json.JSONDecoder(data)
#data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('commandoutputid.json', 'r')]
#data2= json.dumps(data)

### WOULD NOT WORK IF I DIDNT PASS DATA AS A STRING 
### EVEN THOUGH WHEN I PASSED AS A GOOD JSON OBJECT INSIDE AN ARRAY. COULDNT DESERIALIZE

with open('commandoutputid.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file)
      # dumps the json object into an element
    json_str = json.dumps(json_dict)
    # load the json to a string
    dict_str = json.loads(json_str)


url = 'https://...'

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "plain/text"
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer Token"

response = requests.post(url, json=dict_str, headers=headers, verify=False)


with open("backup_output.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    print(response.content)
    print(dict_str)
```

The above script works for passing JSON Object via post in order to return desired output.

My goal is to iterate through hundreds if not thousands of JSON objects to pass VIA POST Request for each JSON Object in the "commandoutputid.json". So instead of the Single POST Request. It would me a Post request per JSON Object in the file.

Comment: `dict_str` is a dictionary, not a string. It's the same as `json_dict`.

Comment: `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` just cancel each other out.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "for each json object in the file"?  a json file must contain **only one** object.  Of course that object can be a container such as a list, but if so, you need to say that.  Or there is a similar json format (actually called `jsonlines`) where each **line** in the file is a separate json object.

Comment: OK. Yes. I could remove two lines of code. But, That isn't the problem.

Comment: Please show a sample of what's in the JSON file (just 2 or 3, not thousands).

Comment: Can you share an example for the content of `commandoutputid.json`? Is it in [JSON Lines format](https://jsonlines.org/) (one JSON object per line) or one JSON Array with multiple objects? Given your description and code example I'm not sure which one it is.

Comment: A Single JSON Object.

Comment: {"deviceId":1077,"aggregationId":"1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5","commandText":"show running-config","logicalSystemName":"<none>","seenAt":"2022-11-15T06:00:01.685243+00:00"}
{"deviceId":1082,"aggregationId":"1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5","commandText":"show running-config","logicalSystemName":"<none>","seenAt":"2022-11-15T06:00:01.705206+00:00"}
{"deviceId":763,"aggregationId":"1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5","commandText":"show running-config","logicalSystemName":"<none>","seenAt":"2022-11-15T06:00:01.698229+00:00"}

Comment: The above includes multiple JSON objects. My Script works as desired when only a single object exists.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes. I have a file that includes hundreds of Individual JSON Objects.

Comment: @Barmar Not the problem at hand. I understand what you're saying. Do you have input about my desire to make multiple post request passing JSON Data. This Script does work on an Individual Object basis.

Comment: If each JSON object is on its own line, you can read a line at a time, call `json.loads()`, then call `request.post()`

Comment: @Barmar So, I need to somehow "normalize" the data so that when it is written to that file it is written line by line? OK. 
--------------




with open('commandoutputid.json', 'w') as f2:
    for url in urls_txt:
        data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        print (data.content.decode('utf-8').strip("[]"), file=f2)

This is the snippet of code I use to write to that file. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should just write the file as a single JSON array. Put all the requests.get results in a list, and then do `json.dump(f2, list_of_results)`

Comment: @Barmar I will give that a shot. seems sound. Thanks!

Comment: raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable

@Barmar  I ran into this before. Thanks for the help either way. Think i have to go a diff route.

Comment: Sorry, had the arguments backwards. `json.dump(list_of_result, f2)`

Answer (score 0):

So you're dealing with an NDJSON (Newline Delimited JSON) instead of a JSON.
http://ndjson.org/

Of course python has a library for it → https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/

Below is a simple load/loop to show how to deal with it.

**main.py**

```py
import ndjson
from pprint import pprint


with open('commandoutputid.ndjson', 'r') as infile:
    all_data = ndjson.load(infile)


for dict_element in all_data:
    print(type(dict_element))
    pprint(dict_element, indent=4)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
ndjson
```

**commandoutputid.ndjson**

```
{"deviceId":1077,"aggregationId":"1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5","commandText":"show running-config","logicalSystemName":"<none>","seenAt":"2022-11-15T06:00:01.685243+00:00"}
{"deviceId":1082,"aggregationId":"1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5","commandText":"show running-config","logicalSystemName":"<none>","seenAt":"2022-11-15T06:00:01.705206+00:00"}
{"deviceId":763,"aggregationId":"1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5","commandText":"show running-config","logicalSystemName":"<none>","seenAt":"2022-11-15T06:00:01.698229+00:00"}
```

**output**

```py
<class 'dict'>
{   'aggregationId': '1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5',
    'commandText': 'show running-config',
    'deviceId': 1077,
    'logicalSystemName': '<none>',
    'seenAt': '2022-11-15T06:00:01.685243+00:00'}
<class 'dict'>
{   'aggregationId': '1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5',
    'commandText': 'show running-config',
    'deviceId': 1082,
    'logicalSystemName': '<none>',
    'seenAt': '2022-11-15T06:00:01.705206+00:00'}
<class 'dict'>
{   'aggregationId': '1aba3c13-5891-4c75-8648-4fe6b954e1f5',
    'commandText': 'show running-config',
    'deviceId': 763,
    'logicalSystemName': '<none>',
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I have been missing. It works! Thank You.